# Python Discordpy Is there a way to modify a message embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

I m writing a bot that create a message, and for each reaction from users it should modify the message and add the user to the embed message, is there any way to do it?

Comment: What's your embed like? And what exactly are you trying to achieve? Please show some code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just send a [`edit_message`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.edit_message) passing the new modified embed contents, and it should work.

Comment: And how i can modify the current embed, becouse if i use message.embeds it return a dict,sorry for all this question i m pretty new in this

Comment: solved by creating a new embeds don't know if there is a smarter solution

Comment: On the old message you can use `message.embeds` http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds

Comment: That will return a list of embeds in the form of a dict, so you cannot use the embeds method

Answer (score 0):

Solved using edit_message, and for embeds i used message.embeds and from the list of dict i have created the new embed, don't why you downvote my post but ok!