# How to edit embed that is from another command? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So i want to make a suggestion system that has ?suggest ?accept and ?deny i already have the code fo ?suggest but i wanna know how to make ?deny and ?accept

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='test')

@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, suggestion):
 embed=discord.Embed(title='Suggestion by {ctx.author.mention}, description=suggestion')
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run(token)
```

this is the code for suggest, i want ?accept to change the color of `embed` to green and add a field with "accepted for reason: {reason}" same as ?deny as well, does anyone know?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please show us what you have tried. Don't expect us to give you the code.

Answer (score -1):

To edit the message you need to get the message:

```
message.id
```

Then use: [`edit_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.edit_message) and create a new embed and put in there.

Source: [Python Discordpy Is there a way to modify a message embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161880/python-discordpy-is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-message-embed)

Comment: Yes but i want it to make the exact same as !suggest but it just edits the color and adds "accepted", i just wanna know how to get the arguments that are from another command

Comment: You can save it. Like a databse

Comment: Also not to mean but if you ur a beginner to python learn the basics before doing dpy

Comment: Lol i know python lmao

Comment: Like in a json file?

Comment: if you want to use json